# Why does C++ Standard 1.9/5 talk about "possible execution sequences"?

Tags: c++

According to C++03 Standard 1.9/5

> A conforming implementation executing a well-formed program shall produce the same observable behavior as one of the possible execution sequences of the corresponding instance of the abstract machine with the same program and the same input.

I don't get the "as one of" part.

If I have a specific program and a specific input and my program doesn't contain undefined behavior why would observable behavior vary? What is meant under "one of the possible execution sequences"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider:

```
x = f() + g();
```

This allows two possible execution sequences:

```
__temp1 = f();           /*or*/     __temp1 = g();
__temp2 = g();           /*or*/     __temp2 = f();
x = __temp1 + __temp2;   /*or*/     x = __temp2 + __temp1;
```

The standard does not specify which of these must be performed; just that the program must behave as if one of these two were performed. If `f()` and `g()` have side effects, then the program could have one of two different observable behaviours.

Comment: Is this limited to unspecified behavior?

Comment: @sharptooth: I guess so. When behaviour is specified, then the program must behave as specified.

Comment: I think this covers both unspecified and implementation-defined behavior. For instance, `sizeof(int)` may determine which possible execution sequence is chosen by an implementation, and yet `sizeof(int)` is not unspecified behavior.

Answer (score 12):

In C++, certain things are left up to the implementation.  For example, when you write

```
int x = f(a) + f(b);
```

The implementation may choose to call f(a) first or f(b) first.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard doesn't define evaluation order for some expressions. For example, in:

```
    proc( a(), b() );
```

both a() and b() have to be evaluated before proc(), but a() may be evaluated before or after b(). So there are two legal execution sequences, and if a() and b() have side effects (eg, print statements), you can tell which the compiler used.

(This freedom about evaluation order is intended to help the compiler generate more efficient code. Whether it does in fact help with modern machines is open to dispute.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the unspecified order in which sub-expressions are evaluated that others have already mentioned, keep in mind that C++11 adds threading, which makes order of execution even less deterministic.

For example, if you have two threads executing, and each just prints out "thread A" or "thread B", the order in which those outputs are produced is entirely unspecified. You might get all of the "thread A" outputs followed by all the "thread B" outputs, or vice versa, or they might be arbitrarily interleaved (with interleaving being more likely).